# Power pivot field list order of columns

Tags: excel

I have a problem with order of field list in power pivot (Excel 2013). IS it possible to order it differently, than in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Got to File > Options > Advanced

Scroll Down until you find `Edit Custom Lists`

You should be able to then define a list you can use in a pivot etc.

Full Explanation In The Link Below

https://sharepointmike.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/create-your-own-custom-list-for-sorting-pivot-rows-and-columns/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am talking about PivotTable filed list, one with fields you use to create pivot table (measures,columns,calculated columns). I have there around 50 and I want to order them in certain way, that it is easy to use. e.g. Have Year,Month,Day together. NOw it is only in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way you can order columns via a list also,  I'll be on excel at some point this week I'll try have a go myself and post new answer if I have any luck